# How can I write a .sol file without using flash?

Tags: flash, amf

Basically, trying to use .sol files to log into a game without having to actually log in. It's just the email and password, in plaintext, though of course in AMF3 or whatever .sol files are. Any ideas on how to do this? I'd like to do it either with AutoHotKey at best, Python at worst, though they shouldn't be that different to work with. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pyamf.org/index.html

This can do it. But AMF is a format that may embed custom serialization, in which case, unless you know how the serializer worked, there's no way to reverse it / write it in the same way.

I'm not sure, but why AIR isn't an option?